# Try to activate a web site feature. Error: Failed to create feature receiver object from assembly

Tags: feature-activation

I am using sharepoint 2007. I have created some custom solution in visual studio 2008. In this solution there is an event receiver "FeatureActivated". I have deployed this wsp to my sharepoint environment. this is the deployment powershell script:

```
myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.Provision.wsp
-   Stsadm –o addsolution –filename myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.Provision.wsp
-   Stsadm –o deploysolution –name myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.Provision.wsp -immediate –allowGacDeployment 

myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.wsp
-   Stsadm –o addsolution –filename myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.wsp
-   Stsadm –o deploysolution –name myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.wsp –url [WEBAPP_URL] -immediate –allowCasPolicies
```

After this I try to activate this web site feature. I got this error:

> Failed to create feature receiver object from assembly
>   myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.Provision, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=33b28a222c369a5a, type
>   myCompany.myCustomer.SharePoint.Demo.Provision.DemoProvisioningFeature
>   for feature 0e2999b0-9abb-473c-8c45-1b0262b0f9b6:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   type  at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()

This custom solution is working on my development environment and the customer test environment. Now I try it on the production environment and get this error when activating the feature in the gui.

Can someone tell me why I get this error? Is the assembly missing or comes this error from the code inside my event receiver "FeatureActivated" method?

Comment: Have you restarted the SharePoint timer service? It is the cause of this issue most of the times

Comment: Yes, my solution is for the case you have had the same .dll deployed before